# select an individual object from hql result

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I write

```
List<Candidate> candidates = (List<Candidate>)session.createQuery("from Candidate as candidate  left outer join candidate.skills as skill    where skill.id ="+ 1).list();
```

I get List of objects, which consists of Candidate object and Skill Object

How can I get only Candidates List ?[image]

Comment: `List<Candidate> candidates` seems like a _Candidates List_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I can't currently remember if this works `from Candidate as candidate where candidate.skills.skill.id = ?`.</strike>

If it doesn't, you can probably use:

`select distinct candidate from Candidate as candidate left outer join candidate.skills as skill where skill.id = ?`

Comment: 1 - SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/ui] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: skill of: com.epam.hhsystem.model.status.Skill [from com.epam.hhsystem.model.candidate.Candidate as candidate where candidate.skills.skill.id =1]] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: skill of: com.epam.hhsystem.model.status.Skill [from com.epam.hhsystem.model.candidate.Candidate as candidate where candidate.skills.skill.id =1]

Comment: @user2645679 you could just write that it does not work :) I have admitted that I was not sure. How about the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you need?

```
for (Candidate candidate:candidates) {
    if(candidate instanceOf Candidate) {
        System.out.println("This is candidate obj : " + candidate.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want just a "join", not a "left outer join".

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) says, "The result of a left outer join (or simply left join) for table A and B always contains all records of the "left" table (A), even if the join-condition does not find any matching record in the "right" table (B)."  In particular an outer join will pull in data from the skills table, which it sounds like you don't want.

Comment: wether I can't specified result?

Comment: If removing "outer" is not helping, I'd try replacing "from Candidate" with "candidate from Candidate".  That makes it explicit that the candidate record is what you want.

Comment: List<Candidate> candidates = (List<Candidate>)session.createQuery(" candidate from Candidate as candidate   join candidate.skills as skill    where skill.id ="+ 1).list();

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!